# Error inserting variable into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var $name = "John Doe";
$.cookie('name', '$name', { expires: 9999, path: '/' });
```

$name variable isn't appearing, should appears "John Doe".

Error image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU9Kc.png**

Comment: You should post the error into your question.

Comment: `$.cookie('name', $name` , dont quote the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.cookie('name', '$name', { expires: 9999, path: '/' });
```

This writes `"$name"` in the cookie, not `"John Doe"`. Try this:

```
$.cookie('name', $name, { expires: 9999, path: '/' });
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't accept your answer yet, give me a few mins.